# Query with 2 Left Join COUNT() takes 30s to execute

Tags: mysql

I have the following 3 tables:

1. giveaway_steps_done
2. giveaways_entries
3. giveaway_steps

giveaway_steps_done

```
id      step_unique_alone
```

giveaways_entries

```
id      giveaway_step_unique
```

giveaway_steps

```
id      step_unique_alone
```

The query list all records from `giveaway_steps`, then it counts the `giveaway_steps_done` records based on `step_unique_alone`. After that it counts `giveaways_entries` records based on `giveaway_step_unique`.

The SQL query works well, but not in the proper way, as it takes 30s to execute and display.

`giveaway_steps_done` has 7000 records. 
`giveaways_entries` has 6800 records.
`giveaway_steps` has 170 records.

Query:

```
SELECT giveaway_steps.*, 
       Count(DISTINCT giveaway_steps_done.id) AS total_steps_count, 
       Count(DISTINCT giveaways_entries.id)   AS total_steps_correct_count 
FROM   giveaway_steps 
       LEFT JOIN giveaway_steps_done 
              ON ( giveaway_steps_done.step_unique_alone = 
                   giveaway_steps.step_unique_alone ) 
       LEFT JOIN giveaways_entries 
              ON ( giveaways_entries.giveaway_step_unique = 
                   giveaway_steps.step_unique_alone ) 
GROUP  BY giveaway_steps.id 
ORDER  BY giveaway_steps.id DESC
```

Sample / Expected

```
id       (giveaway_steps details)  total_steps_count    total_steps_correct_count 
1        blabla  3                                      3
2        blabla  5                                      1
3        blabla  34                                     22
4        blabla  52                                     53
5        blabla  13                                     10
```

The data is correct, but it takes a lot of time. I just want to do a better time/resources consuming query.

How-to redo the issue:

1. Create three tables as stated above.
2. Add the cols as stated above.
3. Add 10/15 records to `giveaway_steps` with different `step_unique_alone`.
4. Add random data to the other tables, and their `step_unique_alone` / `giveaway_step_unique` must match one of those records in `giveaway_steps`.

*The issue is, the query takes time using LEFT JOIN and COUNT().

Comment: eh? why the downvote? I've already explained the whole issue and provided the query?

Comment: I don't know why somebody downvoted your question, but you should check a guide for SQL questions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I guess the sample, but as stated in the question. Sample isn't important as the issue is that the query takes a lot of time, not the expected output isn't correct.

Comment: What are primary keys on this tables? Does it have other index?

Comment: At least post the CREATE statements.

Comment: Primary is ID, FK is step_unique_alone, and is used in other tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This JOIN is inefficient, because it duplicates alot of data.

Assuming that `giveaway_steps.step_unique_alone` is unique and `giveaway_steps_done.step_unique_alone` and `giveaways_entries.giveaway_step_unique` are foreign keys referencing that column. Then there are 7000/170 rows in `giveaway_steps_done` table and 6800/170 rows in `giveaways_entries` per row in `giveaway_steps`. Your JOIN will produce like (7000/170) * (6800/170) rows per "step". That are overall (7000/170) * (6800/170) * 170 which is something like 280K rows. But even with 280K rows it shouldn't take 30 seconds to execute. So I guess that you miss indexes which would support your joins.

To avoid that huge JOIN I would count the related rows in subqueries in the SELECT clause:

```
SELECT giveaway_steps.*, 
    (
        SELECT Count(giveaway_steps_done.id)
        FROM giveaway_steps_done
        WHERE giveaway_steps_done.step_unique_alone = giveaway_steps.step_unique_alone
    ) AS total_steps_count,
    (
        SELECT Count(giveaways_entries.id)
        FROM giveaways_entries
        WHERE giveaways_entries.giveaway_step_unique = giveaway_steps.step_unique_alone
    ) AS total_steps_correct_count 
FROM giveaway_steps
ORDER BY giveaway_steps.id DESC
```

Make sure you have indexes on `giveaway_steps_done.step_unique_alone` and `giveaways_entries.giveaway_step_unique`.

Comment: I've already tried this query. The result from LEFT JOIN produces all the steps (170) with the information for the `total_steps_count` and `total_steps_correct_count`. Using your query, i have only 15 records and not all the 170 records. these 15 records do have a "0" value, and are correct, so the problem isn't "null valued records".

Comment: @Jaeger "Using your query, i have only 15 records and not all the 170 records" - That is not possible. My query has no WHERE (or HAVING) clause, so it should return all rows from `giveaway_steps`.

Comment: My slow query: https://s26.postimg.org/5wlsu4j5l/image.jpg. Your query: https://s26.postimg.org/9g7qjxe5l/image.jpg

Comment: What should I see on you screenshots? There are more than 15 rows. Only differnce I see is the order. Add `ORDER  BY giveaway_steps.id DESC` to my query.

Comment: I'm sorry, that because i've added new steps. The difference is, the slow query includes the whole 170 steps, and your query does not include more than 20-25 records max without including the whole records. After adding your suggestion, the result is still the same, nothing changed only the order has changed, i don't think it has anything to do with fetching the records.

Comment: As I already wrote, my query has no filters, so it should return all rows. Probably your GUI limits the result to 25 rows.